# Show that {$x \in l^\infty: \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=0 \land x_n=0$ for almost all n $\in \mathbb N$} dense in $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A := \{x \in \ell^\infty: \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=0 \land x_n=0$ for almost all $n \in \mathbb N \}$.

How can you prove that $A$ is dense in $\ell^2$ and not in $\ell^1$?
And what is $A^\bot$ in $\ell^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The $\ell^2$ case.** Since $A$ is a linear subspace of $\ell^2$, it is sufficient to show that $A^\bot=\{0\}$. To see this consider $a=(a_n)_n\in A^\bot$. Let $(e_k)_k$ be the canonical basis in $\ell^2$. Since $e_k-e_{k+1}\in A$ for every $k$ we conclude that $\langle a,e_k-e_{k+1}\rangle=0$ for every $k$, that is $\forall\, k,a_k=a_{k+1}$. Hence $a=0$ since it is the only constant sequance in $\ell^2$.

**The $\ell^1$ case.** Any element $u=(u_n)_n\in\overline{A}$, satisfies $\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n=0$. But, there are elements in $\ell^1$ whose sum is not zero, and any one of them does not belong to $\overline{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $\ell_2$:

Note (prove) $A$ is a linear subspace of $\ell_2$; so, it suffices to show that each standard unit vector, $e_i$, belongs to the closure of $A$. 
Towards this end, show that for each $i$, $e_i$ is the limit in $\ell_2$ of the sequence $(x_n)$ where $x_n=e_i-\sum_{k=i+1}^{i+n}{1\over n} e_k$.

For $\ell_1$:

Could $e_1$ be in the closure of $A$?